# hadoop with mrjob piping on shell

Tags: unix, hadoop, pipe, mrjob

I have an issue regarding mrjob.
I'm using an hadoopcluster over 3 datanodes using one namenode and one
jobtracker.
Starting with a nifty sample application I wrote something like the
following

```
first_script.py: 
        for i in range(1,2000000): 
                 print "My Line "+str(i)
```

this is obviously writing a bunch of lines to stdout
the secondary script is the mrjobs Mapper and Reducer.
Calling from an unix (GNU) i tried:

```
python first_script| python second_script.py   -r hadoop
```

This get's the job done but it is uploading the input to the hdfs
completely. Just when everything ist uploaded he is starting the
second job.
So my question is:
Is it possible to force a stream? (Like sending EOF?)
Or did I get the whole thing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you have long since forgotten about this but I'll reply anyway: No it's not possible to force a stream. The whole hadoop programming model is about taking files as input and outputting files (and possibly creating side effects e.g. uploading the same stuff to a database).

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you clarified what you want to achieve a little more.
However it sounds like you might want the contents of a pipe to be periodically processed, rather than wait until the stream is finished.  The stream cant be forced.

The reader of the pipe (your `second_script.py`) needs break its stdin into chunks, either using

- a fixed number of lines like [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39728503/collect-data-in-chunks-from-stdin-python), or
- [non-blocking reads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952473/test-for-new-line-in-stdin) and a preset idle period, or
- a predetermined break sequence emitted from `first_script.py`, such as a 'blank' line consisting of only `\0`.